# Split/separate column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, pivot, crosstab

I'm completely stuck and I cannot find any answers for this problem even though problem seems to be quite simple. Can I separate that 'description' column without making a new table?

For now I just wrote this simplest code.

```
select item_id, description
from data
where item_id = '123'
```

With that code it looks like this:

```
item_id description
123     A
123     B
123     C
```

But I'd like to make it look like this:

```
item_id desc_1 desc_1 desc_2
123     A      B      C
```

Comment: What you're looking for s called `PIVOT`. Some DB providers support it and others don't. Tag your DB in the question

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Yossi, that's true. I'm most likely looking for PIVOT. I'm trying to get data to excel from database.

Data is collected from ERP which is IBS XT Client
http://enterprisehelp.ibs.net/r8/about/common-all-usg/common-all-ibs-enterprise-client-about/#working_with_tables

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation with the help of `case` expression

```
select item_id,
           max(case when description= 'A' then description end) [desc_1],
           max(case when description= 'B' then description end) [desc_2],
           max(case when description= 'C' then description end) [desc_3],
from table
group by item_id
```

**EDIT :** So, the dynamic pivot way will look like as for SQL Server

```
declare @col varchar(max), @q varchar(max)

set @col = stuff(
                    (select distinct ','+quotename('desc_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by Item_id order by description) as varchar)) 
                     from table for xml path('')),
                 1,1,'')

set @q = 'select * from
          (
              select *, 
                    ''desc_''+cast(row_number() over(partition by Item_id order by description) as varchar) rn 
              from table
          )a
          PIVOT
          (
               max(description) for rn in ('+@col+')
          )p'

EXEC (@Q)
```

**Result :**

```
item_id desc_1  desc_2  desc_3
123    A        B       C
234    B        C       d
```

Comment: I don't think this is the correct solution as description might differ with item_id.

Comment: Ankit, thats true. For example in item_id 234 description there could be B,C,D

Answer (score 0):

```
afs -- with clause name
giga -- alias name for listagg


with afs as
 (

select item_id,LISTAGG(description, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY item_id) AS 
giga from test_jk group by item_id

)

select item_id,REGEXP_SUBSTR (giga, '[^,]+', 1, 1)    AS 
desc_1,REGEXP_SUBSTR (giga, '[^,]+', 1, 2)  as desc_2 from afs;
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv1DJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

first Declare Distinct column names 
Like ABC, DEF,GHI
and values 
then write dynamic pivot

```
    DECLARE @COLS AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @COLS=STUFF((select  ',' + QUOTENAME(Course) from cst_coursedetails where programid=1 FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
SET @query =' SELECT *  FROM(SELECT  B.COLLCODE,  B.COLLNAME,C.Course AS COURSE,D.ROLLNAME, E.ExamType, COUNT (A.HTNO) AS PRECOUNT   FROM TableOne AS A
 INNER JOIN TableTwo AS B ON A.COLLCODE=B.COLLCODE AND A.PROGRAMID=B.PROGRAMID  
 INNER JOIN  TableThreee AS C ON C.CourseId=A.CourseId 
 INNER JOIN TableFour AS D ON D.ROLLID=A.ROLLID 
 INNER JOIN  CST_EXAMTYPE AS E ON E.ExamTypeId=A.ExamTypeId
 WHERE A.STATUSID !=17 AND a.ProgramId=1 AND A.ROLLID IN(1,2,3) AND A.EXAMTYPEID IN(1) GROUP BY B.COLLNAME,B.COLLCODE,C.Course,d.ROLLNAME ,E.ExamType  
)SRC
PIVOT(
SUM(PRECOUNT)   FOR  COURSE  IN('+@COLS+')
)AS  PIV'
```